# Generating a JSON formatted table using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to generate a JSON formatted table using data from my database. When doing so, I get the error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in G:\PleskVhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\getData.php on line 23`

I'm not sure why it's giving this error as I did something very similar on another page and it works pefectly fine. Here is my code.

```
<?

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$dbname.";", $username, $password);

$query = $db->query("SELECT 'MAJOR' as 'Major' SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Science',1,0)) as CS, SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Information Systems',1,0)) as CIS, SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Other',1,0)) as Other FROM ages");



$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Major', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'CS', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'CIS', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Other', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = $query->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Major']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['CS']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['CIS']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Other']);

    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

echo $jsonTable;


?>
```

Comment: back ticks not single quotes. Check out the one you said worked. Just get rid of anything around major

Comment: I believe back ticks and single quotes are interchangeable

Comment: To add on to that the actual query I'm storing in $query works because I copied and pasted it into PHP mysql admin and it executed correctly.

Comment: where is your error reporting? Where is your try catch block?

Comment: you have not executed your query $query->execute()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think it is not a back tick issue, as well as an error reporting issue, then run the below. And change the select back ticks to single quotes. And see what you get.

Use the below for a template for how to setup error reporting and a try/catch block.

### Schema

```
create table basic_info2
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    n_id int not null,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    date_released date not null,
    genres varchar(20) not null
);

insert basic_info2(n_id,name,date_released,genres) values (1,'a','2015-04-11','b');
```

### PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$servername = "host";
$username = "dbuser";
$password = "pwd";
$database = "dbname";

try {
    //Make your connection handler to your database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$database, $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

    $sql = "SELECT `N_ID`, `NAME`, `DATE_RELEASED`, `GENRES` FROM basic_info2 ORDER BY N_ID DESC LIMIT 10";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    //Execute the query
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    //Fetch the results
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<p>'.$row['NAME'].'</p>';
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
?>
```

### Edit

concerning you comment below, this is what you had

```
SELECT MAJOR as 'MAJOR'
SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Science',1,0)) as CS, 
SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Information Systems',1,0)) as CIS, 
SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Other',1,0)) as Other 
FROM ages
```

this is what you need (just a missing comma line 1)

```
SELECT MAJOR as 'MAJOR',
SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Science',1,0)) as CS, 
SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Information Systems',1,0)) as CIS, 
SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Other',1,0)) as Other 
FROM ages
```

Comment: After going back and trying to execute my query in PHP myAdmin again it is giving me an error saying an alias was previously found near SUM. Here is the statement
`SELECT MAJOR as 'Major' SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Science',1,0)) as CS, SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Computer Information Systems',1,0)) as CIS, SUM(IF(MAJOR = 'Other',1,0)) as Other FROM ages`.
I tried searching for that error message but couldn't find anything about it.